# Need help using regular expressions to extract data from a line in an error log (Python)

Tags: python, regex, expression, logfile

So I am new to Python and I'm working on a small project that reads through a Windows Event Viewer log file and re-formats the contents of just the error messages. I am trying to do this using regular expressions. The part I am struggling with is extracting the part of the string that explains why the error happened.

For example this is my un-altered string:

> Error  7/8/2021 12:34:04 PM    Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM    10005   None    "DCOM got error ""15612"" attempting to start the service GamingServices with arguments ""Unavailable"" in order to run the server:

I want to be extract the last part:

> "DCOM got error ""15612"" attempting to start the service GamingServices with arguments ""Unavailable"" in order to run the server:

This part of the string has no common symbols that I could use to match with. For example, this is another error log message:

> Error 6/29/2021 3:15:50 PM    Killer Network Service  16  Configuration Files Version Check and Upgrade Version Failed for Configuration File  oem.xml

And I would want to extract:

> Configuration Files Version Check and Upgrade Version Failed for Configuration File  oem.xml

How could I extract the portion of the message that I want? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any whitespace (e.g. newlines) or other delimiter characters that are not showing up here?

Comment: How about get the whole string after the timestamp ?

Answer (score 1):

In regex, you must have a pattern to extract.
Here, I don't see any pattern to split between the service name and the log message.

If there was some split pattern, for example, a special character (even a hyphen or quotes), or a number between the service name and the message, or anything specific - you could split between them and extract the log message.